# Rails jquery-file-upload: Multiple file uploads in a nested file form in a create form results in a separate element made for each upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-file-upload

I've been trying to implement multiple file upload within a create form in Rails using Jquery-file-upload and Carrierwave. It is currently working for both a single file and multiple files, so long as all the multiple files were made in a single selection. If the user attempts to upload multiple files in multiple selections and then clicks submit, instead multiple assignments are created, with each one getting a separate selection attached (with multiple files being attached if that selection had more than one file). So I can make a new element and attach A to it and it will work, or I can make a new element and attach B, C, and D all at once and all three will be attached when the element is made. However, if I attach A, and then before submitting the create form I decide to also attach B and C at the same time, I will end up with two new elements with identical fields except for their IDs and their attachments, where the first one will have A attached and the second one will have B and C.

All the examples I've found of multiple file upload in a create form don't address this specific problem.

Here is my current code. The create form is for Assignments, which have a file form for Receipts (the images to be attached to Assignments).

Assignment Model:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :receipts, :assigned_by, :assigned_to, :deadline, :hours, :name, :notes, :phase_number, :project_number, :ready, :site_id, :status, :support_staff, :category, :receipts_attributes 
  has_many :receipts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :receipts, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  after_save :determine_status
  has_paper_trail :on => [:update, :destroy]


  def task_and_id
    self.category + ' ' + id.to_s
  end

  private
    def determine_status
      if self.status == "Unassigned" && !self.assigned_to.blank?
        self.update_column :status, 'Assignment Pending'
      end
    end
end
```

Assignment Controller (only including the create method)

```
def create
    puts params
    @assignment = Assignment.new(params[:assignment])
    @assignment.status = "Assignment Pending"
    @assignment.ready = true
    if current_user
       @assignment.assigned_by = current_user.id
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignment.save
        user = User.find(@assignment.assigned_to)
        if params[:receipts]
            params[:receipts].each do |receipt|
                @assignment.receipts.create(receipt: receipt)
            end
        end
        UserMailer.other_task_confirmation(user, @assignment).deliver
        if request.xhr? # if its a ajax request then redirect with javascript
            flash[:notice] = 'Your ' + @assignment.category + ' Task has been created.'
            flash.keep(:notice)
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: 'Your ' + @assignment.category + ' Task has been created.' }
        format.json { render json: @assignment, status: :created, location: @assignment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Assignment Form View

```
<%= form_for(@assignment, :url => {:action => 'create'}, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', :id => 'assignment-form', :multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <% if @assignment.errors.any? %>
      <% @assignment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-inputs">


    <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :assigned_by, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" value="<%= current_user.name %>" readonly>
          <%= f.text_field :assigned_by, :value => current_user.id, :style => "display: none" %>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :'Task Name', :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :'Task Type', :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
          <%= f.select :category, options_for_select(tasktype), { :include_blank => "" } %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :assigned_to, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
          <%= f.select :assigned_to, options_for_select(User.where(:is_active => 1).order("name").map{|user| [user.name, user.id]}, @assignment.assigned_to), { :include_blank => "" } %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label 'Project*', :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.collection_select :project_number, Project.where(:is_active => 1).order(:project_number), :project_number, :project_number, :include_blank => true %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group phase-task">
      <%= f.label 'Phase & Task*', :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.grouped_collection_select :phase_number, Project.where(:is_active => 1).order(:project_number), :phases, :project_number, :id, :phase_and_task, :include_blank => true %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :deadline, "Deadline", :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :deadline, :class => 'date_picker' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :hours, "Hours", :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
          <%= f.number_field :hours, :step => 'any' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :notes, "Notes", :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_area :notes, :class => 'span6', :rows => '8' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h4 class="controls">Select Attachments</h4>

    <div id="receipt-list"></div>



      <div class="container" id="fileupload">
    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
      <div class="span7">
        <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
          <%= f.file_field :image, multiple: true, :id => 'uploadbutton', :name => 'assignment[receipts_attributes][][image]' %>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start" id="upload-everything" style="display: none">
          <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
          <span>Start upload</span>
        </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
          <span>Remove all</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" style="display: none">
          <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
          <span>Delete</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" style="display: none">
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
        <!-- The global progress bar -->
        <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade">
          <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
    <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
    <br>
    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
    <table class="table table-striped" id='file-table'><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody>
    </table>
        </div>

</div>
    <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="upload-all">submit</button>
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn', :style => "display: none;", :id => "submit-button" %>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn" id="redirect-button" style="display: none;"></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="redirect-button2" style="display: none;"></button>
<script>
  var fileUploadErrors = {
  maxFileSize: 'File is too big',
  minFileSize: 'File is too small',
  acceptFileTypes: 'Filetype not allowed',
  maxNumberOfFiles: 'Max number of files exceeded',
  uploadedBytes: 'Uploaded bytes exceed file size',
  // emptyResult: 'Empty file upload result'
  };
</script>

<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  <tr class="template-upload fade">
    <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
    <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
    <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
    {% if (file.error) { %}
    <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
    {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
    <td>
      <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
    </td>
    <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
      <button class="btn btn-primary" style="display: none">
        <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
        <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
      </button>
      {% } %}</td>
    {% } else { %}
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="remove">{% if (!i) { %}
      <button class="btn btn-warning">
        <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
      </button>
      {% } %}</td>
  </tr>
  {% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
      {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
        <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
          <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
          {% } %}</td>
        <td class="name">
          <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
      <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% } %}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function () {
      // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
      $('#uploadbutton').attr('name', 'assignment[receipts_attributes][][image]');
      $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        singleFileUploads: false,
        multipart: true,
        done: function (e, data) {
          window.location = "/project_management/show_latest";
        }
      });
      // 
      // Load existing files:
      $.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action'), function (files) {
        var fu = $('#fileupload').data('blueimpFileupload'), 
          template;
        fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
        console.log(files);
        template = fu._renderDownload(files)
          .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'));
        // Force reflow:
        fu._reflow = fu._transition && template.length &&
          template[0].offsetWidth;
        template.addClass('in');
        $('#loading').remove();
      });

  });

  $('#upload-all').click(function() {
    if ($('#file-table tr').length == 0)
    {
      $("#submit-button").trigger("click");
    }
    else {
      $('#upload-everything').trigger("click");
    }
  });


</script>


<% end %>
```

Receipt Model

```
class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchase_expense
  belongs_to :travel_receipt
  belongs_to :purchase
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :other_task
  belongs_to :assignment
  belongs_to :community_service_verification
  belongs_to :community_service_donation_request
  attr_accessible :image, :created_by
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

Receipt Controller (just the create method)

```
def create
@receipt = Receipt.new(params[:receipt])
respond_to do |format|
  if @receipt.save
    format.html {
      render :json => [@receipt.to_jq_upload].to_json,
      :content_type => 'text/html',
      :layout => false
    }
    format.json { render json: {files: [@receipt.to_jq_upload]}, status: :created, location: @receipt }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @receipt.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Let me know if there's any additional information I could provide to help.